# Conditioning on iid sequence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y,X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be real random variables and assume that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d.

Is it true that for any $1\leq i\leq n$: $$\mathbb{E}(Y|X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y|X_i) ? $$

Comment: How is $Y$ related to $X_1,\dots,X_n$?

Comment: Definitely not true in general, take $Y = \sum_i X_i$

Comment: More precisely in my case, $Y$ is a function of only $X_{n+1}$ and $X_{i}$ for a certain $i\leq n$.

Comment: Ok I think it's just that for this certain $i\leq n$, we have the equality I want. Now I need to prove it.